# Is there an analogue of Windows Phone 'User Idle Detection' in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

I've used the following code on Windows Phone 7 and 8 to disable user idle detection when my App is displaying data to the user and they are unlikely to interact with the screen e.g. A recipe App where the screen needs to stay on:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.useridledetectionmode(v=vs.92).aspx

Does anyone know if there is an analogue of this available for Windows 8 applications? My tablet app has the same requirement to disable the screen turning off. I haven't managed to find anything :-(

Many thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [DisplayRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241816.aspx) class, specifically [DisplayRequest.RequestActive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.display.displayrequest.requestactive.aspx) for this purpose.  You must also remember to call DisplayRequest.RequestRelease once you are done to allow the display to sleep, for example, if you are not viewing a recipe, or you are in a menu screen, etc.